# How to split string twice in ansible inventory hosts

Tags: split, ansible, substring, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Below is how i call my `ansible-playbook` for application names `APP1` & `APP2`

```
ansible-playbook -i /web/aes/admin/playbooks/updated.hosts /web/aes/admin/playbooks/split.yml -e ENV=qa -e NODE=cluster -e instance_name=APP1,APP2
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ [ENV] | product(instance_name.split(',')) | product([NODE]) | product(['wladmin_mmsplit'])|map('flatten')|map('join', '_') }}"

  user: wladmin
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -o ConnectionAttempts=20
```

Desired Expected Output:

> PLAY [['qa_APP1_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit',
> 'qa_APP2_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit']]
>
> ---

The issue i now have is the application name is appended by a string like `APP1-brazil` & `APP2-Chile`

Now i will have to further split `instance_name` with hyphen so i could get `APP1` & `APP2` so i tried the below which does not work.

```
- hosts: "{{ [ENV] | product(instance_name.split(',') | split('-')[0]) | product([NODE]) | product(['wladmin_mmsplit'])|map('flatten')|map('join', '_') }}"
```

I get the below error:

```
 ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token ',', got
 '['. String: {{ [ENV] | product(instance_name.split(',') |
 split('-')[0]) | product([NODE]) |
 product(['wladmin_mmsplit'])|map('flatten')|map('join', '_') }}
```

I also tried the below:

```
- hosts: "{{ [ENV] | product(instance_name.split(',')[0].split('-')[0]) | product([NODE]) | product(['wladmin_mmsplit'])|map('flatten')|map('join', '_') }}"
```

But the output is not as expected.

Output:

> PLAY [['qa_A_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit', 'qa_P_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit',
> 'qa_P_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit', 'qa_1_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit']]
>
> ---

Can you please suggest?

Comment: In the future, don't stop typing when writing "does not work" because the ways it can "not work" are infinite. When trying it locally, it trivially produced `'list object' has no attribute 'split'.` because `-e` values are subject to coercion. Anyway, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74921661/edit) and include your specific error

Comment: @mdaniel i updated the original post with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the ***edited*** playbook that will do the job for you by passing the parameter from the command line. It was a bit tricky though but it is working now

```
---
- name: "{{ ENV.split() | product(range(0,instance_name | split(',') | map('split','-') | list | flatten | list | length, 2) | map('extract', instance_name     | split(',') | map('split','-') | list | flatten | list) | list )  | map('join', '_') | product(NODE.split()) |  map('join', '_') | product(['wladmin_mmsplit']) | map('join', '_') |  join(',')  }}"
  hosts: localhost
  become: true

  tasks:

    - name: Generate the range
      copy:
        content: "hello world"
        dest: count.txt
```

And below is the output of the playbook.

```
 ansible-playbook split_final.yml -e ENV='qa' -e NODE='cluster' -e instance_name='APP1-brazil,APP2-Chile'

PLAY [qa_APP1_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit,qa_APP2_cluster_wladmin_mmsplit] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Generate the range] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: can u update your solution with vars: instance_name as parameter passed with `-e` rather than hard coding  `instance_name: ["{{ 'APP1-brazil' | regex_replace('-.*$', '') }}","{{ 'APP2-Chile' | regex_replace('-.*$', '') }}"]`

Comment: can u have a look

Comment: @Ashar..it is done. please accept if you are satisfied with the answer

Comment: I see hardcoded `  vars:
    ENV: ["qa"]
    NODE: ["cluster"]
    concat_string: ["wladmin_mmsplit"]` while i tried to pass them as variables and it does not give me the desired output `-e ENV=qa -e NODE=cluster` @isilia ... Is it possible to have some solution with parameters passed as is in my original post?

Comment: @Ashar..it will work now , please check and confirm